# Python: remove/filter equals sign from list

Tags: python, list, substring

Quick question because I'm stuck and cannot seem to get any further.

Here is my problem:

I'm working in a dataset where I'm extracting every section name of a Wikipedia page from an XML dump. I extract the text and from the text, every section is given through:

==Section Name==

However, there are also subsections which I do not want to process and are given through

===Section Name===

Currently I am using a regex to filter the sections from the text (pagetext)

```
sections = re.findall("==(.*)==", pagetext)
```

The result however is is that the subsections are included in my list of sections as well. Question: how can I filter these subsections from my list of sections in order to only retrieve the sections from the text.

I have used this list comprehension but that does not work

```
sections = [section for section in sections if section[0] == (r"^=")]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated:) Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: To be clear, are you processing the XML directly with regular expressions, or are you converting the XML to something else, first?

Comment: No, first I processed the XML to reach the <text> tag and tried to find the sections within that text tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the surrounding text is completely arbitrary, you might have to resort to [negative lookahead and negative lookbehind](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

```
re.findall(r'(?<!=)==(?!=)(.*?)(?<!=)==(?!=)', pagetext)
# (?<!...) only matches if not preceded by ...
# (?!...) only matches if not followed by ...
# (.*?) the captured group itself, anything matched non-greedily
```

This ensures that the section enclosing `'=='` are neither preceded or followed by a `'='`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable the multiline flag `re.M` so that the expression can be anchored at the beginning of the line.
2. Anchor the expression at the beginning of each line.
3. Exclude subsections in your original regex by excluding the third equals sign

for example

```
sections = re.findall("^==([^=].*)==", pagetext, re.M)
```

Comment: This will still find the sections enclosed by three '=' signs.